# Shared Preferences bug in Android - All saved values are the same

Tags: android, mobile, sharedpreferences, counter

I'm making a simple counter app and I'd like for my counts to save when the app closes.
At the moment, the last count assigned to the saving variable is written to all the saving variables: `editor.putString(A_COUNT, String.valueOf(aCount));` That is to say, when I open the app after closing it, all of my counts show the last value of aCount. If I change the last line to `editor.putString(F_COUNT, String.valueOf(fCount));`, then the value of fCount is saved to all of the variables.
Any idea why this is happening? I'm using integer variables to hold the count values and I have to use conversion methods to pass them back and forth to the TextViews in the main activity... it's easier to increment them that way but I'm sure there's a better way to do it. I'm also sure this could mess things up in some way.
I'd appreciate any advice!

Here's me code. My guess is that I've made a mistake in my saveData() method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static String SHARED_PREFS = "sharedPrefs";
public static String F_COUNT = "0";
public static String Z_COUNT = "0";
public static String A_COUNT = "0";
public static String M_COUNT = "0";
public static String I_COUNT = "0";
private static int fCount = 0;
private static int zCount = 0;
private static int aCount = 0;
private static int mCount = 0;
private static int iCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadData();
    updateViews();
}
public void saveData(){ //putting int counts into string local data
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(F_COUNT, String.valueOf(fCount));
    editor.putString(Z_COUNT, String.valueOf(zCount));
    editor.putString(I_COUNT, String.valueOf(iCount));
    editor.putString(M_COUNT, String.valueOf(mCount));
    editor.putString(A_COUNT, String.valueOf(aCount));
    editor.apply();
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(mCount), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void loadData(){ //loading string local data into int counts
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    fCount = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(F_COUNT, "0"));
    zCount = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(Z_COUNT, "0"));
    aCount = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(A_COUNT, "0"));
    iCount = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(I_COUNT, "0"));
    mCount = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(M_COUNT, "0"));
    Toast.makeText(this, F_COUNT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
public void updateViews(){ //settings int counts to textViews
    TextView fNum = findViewById(R.id.fNum12);
    fNum.setText(String.valueOf(fCount));

    TextView zNum = findViewById(R.id.fNum7);
    zNum.setText(String.valueOf(zCount));

    TextView aNum = findViewById(R.id.fNum14);
    aNum.setText(String.valueOf(aCount));

    TextView iNum = findViewById(R.id.fNum17);
    iNum.setText(String.valueOf(iCount));

    TextView mNum = findViewById(R.id.fNum13);
    mNum.setText(String.valueOf(mCount));
}
```

Comment: Your keys need to have different values from each other; e.g., `public static String F_COUNT = "f_count";`, `public static String Z_COUNT = "z_count";`, etc.

Comment: Woah, it works! Thanks so much! But why does the fact that they all have the same value cause that?

Comment: Those `String` values are the names used to set and look up the individual values in `SharedPreferences`. When they were all the same name – `"0"` – `SharedPreferences` couldn't tell them apart, basically. Make sense?

Comment: It's like if you are storing data in a db, if you use the same key you will overwrite an existing value instead of writing a new record inside the db. (SharedPreferences isn't  db I was writing an example, SharedPreferences is a XML)

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. I thought I was just initializing the Strings. Thank you!